# How can we write any currency symbol in visual studio?

Tags: reactjs, visual-studio-code

I am working on a WebApp using React and have to use various currency symbols but dollar symbol is provided to us in keyboard only. So, how could i use differnt currency sysmbols?
Is there some solution common to all platforms or specific one for VS code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to install this library

[currency-symbol](https://www.npmjs.com/package/currency-symbol)

Example

```
//ES5
const currencySymbol = require('currency-symbol');
 
// ES6
import currencySymbol from 'currency-symbol';
 
console.log(currencySymbol.all());
// This will return all curriencies symbol
 
console.log(currencySymbol.symbol("United States")); //&#36;
// This will return '&#36;' which is $.
 
console.log(currencySymbol.symbol("USD")); //&#36;
// This will return '&#36;' which is $.
 
console.log(currencySymbol.symbol("Dollar")); //&#36;
// This will return '&#36;' which is $.
 
console.log(currencySymbol.symbol("Nigeria")); //&#8358;
// This will return '&#8358;' which is ₦.
 
console.log(currencySymbol.symbol("NGN")); //&#8358;
// This will return '&#8358;' which is ₦.
 
console.log(currencySymbol.symbol("Naira")); //&#8358;
// This will return '&#8358;' which is ₦.
 
console.log(currencySymbol.symbol("GHC")); //&#162;
// This will return '&#162;' which is ¢
 
console.log(currencySymbol.symbol("Ghana")); //&#162;
// This will also return '&#162;' which is ¢
 
console.log(currencySymbol.symbol("Cedis")); //&#162;
// This will also return '&#162;' which is ¢.
 
/***
* Note: the .symbol() function takes any of this arguments - Country Name, Currency Name and Currency Abbreviation and return the currency symbol.
***/
```

You need to use above library or use code like this for related currency like this `&#36;` for dollar